# server-side control - how set background with css ? (link & hover)

Tags: asp.net, css, background, hover, server-side

i am so cofused for choosing between a control (asp.net) or an element (html) for having a button with background that is set with css.(background will change in hover...)

1-at first it seems asp.net ImageButton control is not good for this purpose , because my background has transparecy inside , so when we set it with css  an icon appears up to the ImageButton in ie (ie default image icon).

2-serverside button control is not good for this purpose , because when we set it's backgroung with css , so it seems there is a border around background.

3-background setting with css does not work for link button!!

4-HTML elements do n't have server side onclick event
e.g the below code does not work :

```
            <div runat="server" onclick="serverside">
            </div>
```

would u plz learn me how can i do this job ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer comes from the answer to this que4stion: do you know enough to decide in the browser, or do you need to ask the server.

If you just want to change the background on hover, use CSS.  There is [a `hover` property in CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/sel_hover.asp) that you can use, or you can get more complicated behavior with Javascript in the browser.

If you need to, say, query the database to make the decision, first:

- ask yourself why you want to do a thing like that -- that will impose a significant delay between the time the conditi0ns for the change are met and the time the reply can get back.
- then you'll need some javascript to respond to the server, or else the server will have to serve the page again.

Comment: thanks @Charlie Martin for answer / i have some server side codes (e.g getting data from database) that should i use in onclick of that button - i know css sodoclass hover , but i do n't know how combine css hover & server-side onclick event & html element!